# Node JS - Osmosis form .submit

Tags: node.js, osmosis

I'm currently using `osmosis` to scrape information which is inside various accounts. In order to login to these accounts I'm trying to use the `submit` command. It however doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried `.login` but this seems to not recognize the form at all.

The documentation seems to be lacking any examples. Anyone experience with `.submit` using `osmosis`?

```
osmosis
    .get(url)
    .submit("form", {'gebruikersnaam': username, 'wachtwoord': password})
    .log(console.log)
    .error(console.log)
    .debug(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

It varies from website to website. I'm assuming the website you're trying to login is using ajax of some sort. If `.submit` didn't work out, you could try to do `.post`. Here is the workaround example. Try and see if it work.

1. Get cookie via post login. first osmosis instance
2. Set the cookie in `.config` in second osmosis instance

Code:

```
osmosis
.get(loginUrl)
.post(loginPosturlTarget, {'username': username, 'password': password})
.then((context)=>{
    // store cookies after post login.
    let cookies = cookie.parse(context.request.headers['cookie']);
    scrapeData(cookies);

})
.log(console.log)
.error(console.log)
.debug(console.log);

function scrapeData(cookies){
    // do the actual scraping here with the cookie here
    osmosis
    .config('cookies', cookies)
    .get(url) 
    // your follow/set/paginate/whatever chain here
    .data((data)=> {
        // do something with the data
    })
    .log(console.log)
    .error(console.log)
    .debug(console.log);
}
```

It doesn't guarantee to work in your case, but I found this working on most of the site I've worked on. If still didn't work, perhaps try other alternative modules like [nightmareJs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare).